# Finding new elements in JSON array and update spreadsheet

Tags: json, vba, parsing

I am parsing my JSON list everyday to my Excel spreadsheet. It is a list of around 400-500 user info and everyday it is being updated. Now because i don't want to parse the same list everyday, i just need to locate the new objects that are added to the JSON and comparing it with the existing parsed list in Excel. New objects will be added if not found. This is my code below:

```
Private Sub populate_Click()

Dim http As Object, JSON As Object, Item As Variant
Dim i As Integer

Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
http.Open "GET", "http://controlpanel.verio/rest/reports?errorMessages=null", False
http.send

Dim jsnStr As Object
Set jsnStr = ParseJson(http.responseText)
'Fetching data
i = 3
For Each Item In jsnStr("results")(1)("results")

    Dim findy As Variant
    findy = Item(4)
    Columns("B:B").Select
    Set cell = Selection.Find(What:=findy, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext)

    If cell Is Nothing Then
    'do it something
    Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value = Item(3)
   Sheets(1).Cells(i, 2).Value = Item(4)
   Sheets(1).Cells(i, 5).Value = Item(18)
   Sheets(1).Cells(i, 6).Value = Item(6)
   Sheets(1).Cells(i, 7).Value = Item(7)
   Sheets(1).Cells(i, 8).Value = Item(8)
   Sheets(1).Cells(i, 9).Value = Item(5)
   Sheets(1).Cells(i, 11).Value = Item(20)

    i = i + 1
    Else
    'do it another thing
    End If

Next
Set JSON = Nothing
Set http = Nothing

End Sub
```

I am not receiving any error but nothing is changed or updated from the excel list.

**What should I correct in the below code?**

Comment: Have you tried stepping thru it using F8 to see where your logic is breaking down?

Comment: @braX the code is working fine without the part “dim findy...set cell”. However once I put this lookup part including the IF statement, CELL is returning nothing.

Comment: Try `LookIn:=xlValues`

Comment: @TimWilliams ok so i added a lastrow property that detect the rows count and then append the missing values after the last row. Now it’s working perfectly.

Comment: Good to hear you got it working.

Comment: @Leb_Broth Could you please post an answer then and accept it, just to make the solution clear?

Comment: @omegastripes sure I’ll do it in the morning as I’m away from the code but thanks for reminding me